# Signals VS Celery task

Tags: django, celery, django-signals

So i have this scenario and quite not sure whether celery is the right tool for the job. 
I have to track the fifth order placed by a user to give them a coupon. Currently i have implemented a signal on the

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Order)
def pre_save_stuff():
     #this has overhead on db since am excluding customers not in 
     #loyalty progamme.They are many
     do_coupon_stuff()
```

method. However i have now to exclude a particular group of customers with a query that has overhead slowing the request cycle for this order. Does it make sense to user celery in this scenario?

Comment: If you can post your `do_coupon_stuff` function, it will be good to get good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give coupon in the response itself. You have to do this. Otherwise just give the task to background (`celery` is an option)

Comment: Actually the coupon is not for this response i am sending it with email to be used the next time. Thanks

Comment: So you can do asynchronously using celery.